# SQL Query Will Time Out

Tags: mysql

I don't know how to stop my query from timing out. I have two tables. One with payment details including a postcode field. Example of `payments` table;

```
id (PRI) | company_name | amount | postcode
1          ACME           10000    AB1 1AA
2          Some Int.      15000    ZY9 8XW
```

The other table is a lookup table which assigns geographical regions to the postcodes. Example of `postcode` table;

```
postcode | country | county | local_authority | gor
AB1 1AA    S99999    E2304     X               45
AB1 1AB    S99999    E2304     X               45
```

So if a user does a search on `country = S99999` it will return all the payments for that country.

The `payments` table has 40,000 rows. The `postcode` table has over 2,500,000. Even this really simple query will time out;

```
SELECT t1.company_name, t1.amount, t1.postcode, t2.country, t2.county, t2.local_authority, t2.gor 
FROM `payments` as t1 LEFT JOIN `postcodes` AS t2 ON t1.`postcode` = t2.`postcode`
```

I have an INDEX on both `postcode` fields on both tables. I cannot manually add the lookup fields on to my `payments` table because their is a different lookup for each quarter.

I am limited in my experience here. I cannot think of alternatives or ways around this. Any ideas?

Comment: I think your 'LEFT JOIN' is the killer. For now, change it into a normal 'JOIN'. Does it still time out? :)

Comment: Does a user always have to do a search to trigger this query? You might want to try this: SELECT * FROM payments WHERE postcode IN (SELECT postcode FROM postcode WHERE (country='S99999'));

Comment: Taking out `LEFT` is a quick win for now. That helps a lot. And on your second comment; I'm sure I read somewhere that a JOIN is a lot faster than doing an IN? But if the IN is a nested query then you could be right :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll make an answer from my comments as well:

I think your 'LEFT JOIN' is the killer. For now, change it into a normal 'JOIN'. Does it still time out? :)

And you might want to create a view with the query. The first time it will be slow but then the data will (probably) be available in a cache. But you might want to read the documentation of the DBMS about that. :)

Does a user always have to do a search to trigger this query? You might want to try this:

```
    SELECT * FROM payments WHERE postcode IN (SELECT postcode FROM postcode WHERE (country='S99999'));
```

Edit: the nested query might take more memory. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what DB you using, but in case of SQL server:

1. Limit the count of returned recors (TOP clause)
2. use hint NO LOCK to improve speed of the query
3. increase command timeout of your query, but no more that web page timeout
4. don't use LEFT JOIN, it is slow
5. use temp table (or in memory table), where to store you data from both tables and than just filter the data

Comment: Thanks. I can't get NO LOCK to work. I've put it in various places in the code and still nothing. Could you provide an example in your answer?

Comment: SELECT TOP 1000 [ItemId]
      ,[ItemType]
      ..............
  FROM [WebDav].[dbo].[Item] WITH(NOLOCK)